# LINQ select from Queryable joining a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using EF to join on a table using a list.

I have the attendance table :

```
Attendance
----------
UserBaseId
ClassroomID
Attendance Status ...etc
```

Also, 
I have an attendance IEnumerable in memory, of the same structure, let's call it newAttendance.

I need to find all records from the attendance table which matches the UserBaseId and ClassroomId in the newAttendance List.

so far I have tried this,

```
var entriesInAttendanceTable = context.Attendance.Where(
            x => (newAttendance .Select(i => i.UserBaseId).Contains(x.UserBaseId))
            && newAttendance .Select(i => i.ClassRoomId).Contains(x.ClassRoomId)
            ).ToList();
```

this results in the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 

[Extent1].[ClassRoomId] AS [ClassRoomId], 

[Extent1].[UserBaseId] AS [UserBaseId], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Extent1].[UpdatedOn] AS [UpdatedOn], 
[Extent1].[UpdatedByUser_Id] AS [UpdatedByUser_Id], 
[Extent1].[CreatedByUser_Id] AS [CreatedByUser_Id]
FROM [dbo].[Attendance] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    WHERE 1 = 0
)) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
    WHERE 1 = 0
))
```

Also tried join but it didnt work.

TIA

Comment: What happens when you call .ToList(), to actually execute the query at this place? also, you should select the ids in memory, not inside the query.

Comment: does not select anything, although I have entries which match the criteria., updated question with SQL query

Comment: What does the `var x in y` syntax mean? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @smead copy/paste error. corrected

Comment: WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    WHERE 1 = 0
this looks like there are no entries in newAttendance it would like to pass to the query. Try selecting the Id's into variables and then call the DB without select on your IEnumerables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do what you want:

```
var entriesInAttendanceTable = context.Attendance.Where(x => (newAttendance.Any(
    y => y.UserBaseId == x.UserBaseId && y.ClassRoomId == x.ClassRoomId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In general this is not supported, so you either need to

(A) build and execute `UNION` query like this:

```
var entriesInAttendanceTable = newAttendance
    .Select(y => context.Attendance.Where(x => y.FirstName == x.FirstName && y.LastName == x.LastName))
    .Aggregate(Queryable.Union)
    .ToList();
```

(B) build and execute `OR` based query like this:

*Helpers:*

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Match<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> target, Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> by)
    {
        var parameter = by.Parameters[0];
        var condition = target
            .Select(item => by.Body.ReplaceParameter(by.Parameters[1], Expression.Constant(item)))
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse) ?? Expression.Constant(false);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(condition, parameter);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }

    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var entriesInAttendanceTable = context.Attendance
    .Match(newAttendance, (x, y) => y.FirstName == x.FirstName && y.LastName == x.LastName)
    .ToList();
```

Please note that both solutions might be problematic if the `newAttendance` list is big.